# Favicon showing blank in Firefox using html5

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, favicon

I have put in code using html5. In Firefox, the Favicon is showing as blank. In Internet Explorer, the favicon is showing as intended.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="icon" href="http://www.bunchofus.com/Bicon.ico" />
```

Tried the below as well.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.bunchofus.com/Bicon.ico" />
```

I tried clearing the cache and restarting the browser and neither worked. I would appreciate the help as to why this is happening.

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I can see your favicon is blank.  Looks like a blank square in Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you rename the icon favicon.ico, which normally means you don't need to hint the favicon path to browsers.

Additionally, check that the format of your image is correct and try regenerating the .ico from your original source as browsing directly to it in some browsers doesn't show the red "B", which suggests an issue with the image.